# Downloading UIImages from dropbox

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I am trying to download some images from Dropbox in this way:

```
-(void)catchTheImage{

NSString *title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Folder3"];
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
NSString *filename2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@photofile.png.%ld", title, (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber];

NSString *tmpPngFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename2]];

[restClient loadFile:filename2 intoPath:tmpPngFile];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(lf) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)lf{

NSString *tmpPngFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename2]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tmpPngFile];
photoView.image = image;
}
```

I know the timer isn't a good idea but its just for trying.
TagNumber can be 1, 2, or 3 since the images on dropbox are 3, but the images are not showing up. I think they are not saved in the folder at all. May be I have a misunderstanding of how NSTemporaryDirectory works...

Comment: Get rid of the timer. You need to implement the Dropbox delegate methods that are called when the file is actually downloaded. You would load the image from the temp directory at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement Dropbox delegate methods that will return a status about your loading process

here it is

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath;
// Implement the following callback instead of the previous if you care about the value of the
// Content-Type HTTP header and the file metadata. Only one will be called per successful response.
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString*)destPath;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

and in your case:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

NSString *tmpPngFile = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename2]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tmpPngFile];
photoView.image = image;

}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!!!" message:@"Try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
```